# Swift, how to set Parse default ACL

Tags: swift, parse-platform, acl

I'm trying to set the default ACL in the AppDelegate.  According to the documentation it states to use...

```
PFACL.setDefaultACL(PFACL.ACL(), withAccessForCurrentUser: true)
```

However when I use this I get an error on the line that reads...

```
'ACL()' is unavailable: use object construction 'PFACL()'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message states, you should use

```
PFACL.setDefaultACL(PFACL(), withAccessForCurrentUser: true)
```

so the constructor is just `PFACL()`.

Comment: Before,You have to assign your applicationid and clientkey.    <br/>Parse.setApplicationId("your_application_id", clientKey: "your_client_key")